# How to get data from next auth signIn Google provider in custom signIn page?

Tags: google-authentication, next-auth, sanity

I need to get the data from the custom signIn page in order to write a user to the sanity database. But these signIn data is only obtained in [...nextauth].js file.

Code:

[...nextauth].js

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import GoogleProvider from 'next-auth/providers/google'

export default NextAuth({
  // Configure one or more authentication providers
  providers: [
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: "xxxxxx",
      clientSecret: "xxxxx",
    }),
    // ...add more providers here
  ],
  secret: "something",

  pages: {
    signIn: '/auth/signin',
  },
  callbacks: {
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      session.user.username = session.user.name
        .split(' ')
        .join('')
        .toLocaleLowerCase()

      session.user.uid = token.sub

      return session
    },
  },
})
```

And these session data can be used inside components using useSession from next-auth.

But while trying to get the data to my custom signIn page, session is undefined.

```
import { getProviders, signIn as signIntoProvider } from "next-auth/react";
import { sanityClient } from "../../sanity";
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/react';

function signIn({users}) {
  const { data: session } = useSession()

  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    fetch("/api/createUser", {
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then((resp) => {
        console.log(resp);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };

  const checkIfUserThere = async () => {
    let newUser = session.user.email;
     for (const data of users) {
      if (data.email === newUser) {
        return true;
         }
     }
 
      return false;
   };

   useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const userExists = await checkIfUserThere();
      if(userExists === false ){
        onSubmit(session.user); //write to sanity database
      }
    })();
  }, []);

  return (
        <>
                <button
                  className="rounded-lg bg-blue-500 p-3 text-white"
                  onClick={() =>
                    signIntoProvider("google", { callbackUrl: "/" })
                  }
                >
                  Sign in with Google
                </button>
    </>
  );
}
```

The above code is for a custom signIn page.
What is expected :
Once the user clicks the sign-in with the Google button, the session data must be added to the sanity database. But in my case, session here is undefined.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to write the logic inside the `[...nextAuth].js` file.

To solve the task of popularizing a document in Sanity from a Google authentication, you must first establish a connection to your Sanity project. Note that this import comes from the `'npm i @sanity/client'` package or '`yarn add @sanity/client`' and is not a reference to the configuration located in the `sanity.js` file. To do this, you can import the `@sanity/client` library and set up a configuration to connect to your project:

```
import sanityClient from "@sanity/client";

const config = {
  dataset: "DATASET_NAME",
  projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
  useCdn: 'CDN'
  token: "YOUR_TOKEN_SANITY",
};

export const client = sanityClient(config);
```

After setting up authentication with Google, you must set up a callback to run every time a user authenticates. This callback should look in Sanity to see if the user already exists, and if not, create a new user document in Sanity with the authenticated user's information:

```
const populateSanityUser = async (user) => {
  const sanityUser = await client.fetch(
    `*[_type == "users" && email == "${user.email}"]{ //check if the email exists
                email
            }`
  );
  if (sanityUser.length > 0) { //if exists
    return sanityUser;
  } else { //if not, create a new user with Google user session data
    try {
      await client.create({
        _type: "user",
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email,
        urlImage: user.image,
        ... // another field in your document
      });
      return user;
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
};

export default NextAuth({
  ...authOptions,
  callbacks: {
    async signIn(user) {
      const isAllowedToSignIn = true; //optional
      if (isAllowedToSignIn) {
        const sanityUser = await populateSanityUser(user.user);
        return sanityUser;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    },
  },
});
```

**Important:** Make sure that when you pass the `user` coming from **NextAuth callback** function you use `user.user`, as it comes nested with more data.

More information about callbacks in NextAuth here: https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks